# Como pegar valores de um listview em outra pagina.xaml

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8-1

> Eu tenho essa classe que preenche os valores no listview.

```
    public Lista()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    carregaLista();
}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
public async void carregaLista()
{

    var local = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "hinos.sqlite");
    SQLiteAsyncConnection con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(local, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    listaHinos.ItemsSource = await con.Table<hinos>().ToListAsync();
}

public void listaHinos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail), listaHinos);
}
```

> A intenção é clicar no item e detalha-lo na outra página

```
    public void listaHinos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail), listaHinos);
}
```

> O código esta funcionando, não sei se passei errado, gostaria de acessar os valores do listview selecionado na outra página.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer acessar o item selecionado, certo? Do modo atual, você está enviando todo o `ListView` para a próxima página. Ao invés disto, envie apenas o objeto selecionado utilizando o `SelectedItem`

```
public void listaHinos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //estou considerando que "hinos" seja sua classe
    hinos hino = (hinos)listaHinos.SelectedItem;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail), hino);
}
```